# Dynamically retrieve the object, Spring MVC, JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have jsp page for create a new issue (Entity in my project), using this part of code:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <nobr><label>Project</label></nobr>
        <c:if test="${!empty userProjects}">
            <sf:select path="projectId" cssClass="selectpicker">
                <c:forEach items="${userProjects}" var="project">
                    <sf:option value="${project.id}">${project.nameOfTheProject}</sf:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </sf:select>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty userProjects}">
            There are no projects
        </c:if>
    </div>
```

I select the project for join current issue to this selected above project. Next on the same page here:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <nobr><label>Who will fix the issue?</label></nobr>
        <c:if test="${!empty project.usersInTheCurrentProject}">
            <sf:select path="fixerId" cssClass="selectpicker">
                <c:forEach items="${project.usersInTheCurrentProject}" var="user">
                    <sf:option value="${user.id}">${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</sf:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </sf:select>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty project.usersInTheCurrentProject}">
            There are no users
        </c:if>
    </div>
```

I need to get project selected before, for getting users list from this project, how can I implement that? Thanks.

Comment: Referring to your problem it seems that you need to implement cascading type drop down as per my understanding,that is depending upon project selection(projectId) you want to show list of users Is this understanding right ?

Comment: yeah. something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax call to fetch list of users and controller to return list through json response.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <nobr><label>Project</label></nobr>
    <c:if test="${!empty userProjects}">
        <sf:select path="projectId" cssClass="selectpicker">
            <c:forEach items="${userProjects}" var="project">
                <sf:option value="${project.id}">${project.nameOfTheProject}</sf:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </sf:select>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty userProjects}">
        There are no projects
    </c:if>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Who will fix the issue?</label>
    <c:if test="${!empty project.usersInTheCurrentProject}">
        <sf:select id="fixerId" path="fixerId" cssClass="selectpicker">
        </sf:select>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty project.usersInTheCurrentProject}">
        There are no users
    </c:if>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {


                    $('#projectId')
                                .change(
                                        function() {

                                            $
                                                    .getJSON(
                                                            '${getUsersByProject}',
                                                            {
                                                                projectId : $(
                                                                        this)
                                                                        .val(),
                                                                ajax : 'true'
                                                            },
                                                            function(data) {
                                                                var html = '<option value="">--Select Users--</option>';
                                                                var len = data.length;
                                                                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                                                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                                                                            + data[i].firstName + data[i].lastName
                                                                            + '</option>';
                                                                }
                                                                html += '</option>';

                                                                $(
                                                                        '#fixerId')
                                                                        .html(
                                                                                html);
                                                            });
                                        });


                    });
</script>
```

Controller Code to fetch users.

```
public List<Users> getAllUsersByProjectId(Model model,
        @RequestParam long projectId) {
    List<User> userList = null;
    try {
        //service which will return list of users

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        model.addAttribute(Constants.EXCEPTIONSTRING, ex);
    }
    return userList;
```

}

Comment: it doesnt work for me( after changing select with projects nothing going on.

Comment: Can you specify your problem in bit detailed form.